# How to invoke a REST call (POST with JSON body) from Camel in blueprint

Tags: json, apache-camel, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I want to call a POST rest service in camel blueprint. My blueprint xml file is the following:

```
<blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
xmlns:cxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="      http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0       https://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd      http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint       http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd      http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd">
<bean class="org.apache.cxf.jaxrs.provider.json.JSONProvider" id="jsonProvider"/>
<cxf:rsClient address="http://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
    id="rsClient" loggingFeatureEnabled="true">
    <cxf:providers>
        <ref bean="jsonProvider" component-id="jsonProvider"/>
    </cxf:providers>
</cxf:rsClient>
<camelContext id="RESTCamelContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
    <route id="RESTRoute">
        <from id="_from1" uri="timer:foor?repeatCount=1"/>
        <to id="_to1" uri="log:body?level=INFO"/>
        <setHeader headerName="Content-Type" id="_setHeader1">
            <constant>application/json</constant>
        </setHeader>
        <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_METHOD" id="_setHeader2">
            <constant>POST</constant>
        </setHeader>

        <to id="_to2" uri="cxfrs:bean:rsClient"/>
        <to id="_to3" uri="log:body?level=INFO"/>
    </route>
</camelContext>
```

but I don't know how to pass the JSON object in the body request.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The easiest way would be to use [HTTP4 component](https://camel.apache.org/http4.html):

```
<setHeader headerName="CamelHttpMethod">
    <constant>POST</constant>
</setHeader>
<setBody>  make your POJO here </setBody>
<marshal>
    <json library="Jackson" />
</marshal>
<to uri="http4://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"/>
```

Comment: How can I set the JSON object of my POJO class to post?

Comment: Just set the body to your POJO object and add a `marshal` step to convert it to JSON using your preferred library

Comment: Thank you. Can yuo tell me how this can be translated in code?

Comment: Ok. It works. Can I ask you another question? How can I read the response unmarshalling it into a Json object?

Comment: And how can I parse a response with a list of json objects?

Comment: You can see the examples [here](https://camel.apache.org/json)
As for the list, the easiest way to deserialize it would be to create your own type e.g. `MyListPojo extends ArrayList<Pojo>` and then use it as an `unmarshalTypeName`

Comment: Thank you again. The last question :).. Can I print (log) the http request passed to the http4 component?

Comment: You can add a log step after the marshal step

Comment: But I see only the body content

Comment: That's because you chose to show only the body - your expression probably used only the ${body} placeholder, but you can use whatever you want - see the simple language reference

Comment: Hi, when the request is about 3MB, the http4 component blocks on socket reading thread and I cannot retrieve the response. With postman I successfully get the response in few milliseconds. This is the stacktrace of the thread.


`java.net.SocketOutputStream . socketWrite0  (SocketOutputStream.java) (Native)
java.net.SocketOutputStream . socketWrite  (SocketOutputStream.java:113)
java.net.SocketOutputStream . write  (SocketOutputStream.java:159)`

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with Camel itself, I guess it's related to Apache's HttpClient. You should probably open up a new question for it, I don't have any ideas from the top of my head.

Comment: I resolved using a custom Processor and importing the org.apache.httpcomponents library. Thank you